# Restarting the while loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to restart the while loop. I've declared variable keepGoing of boolean type. If int variable x is off the window, keepGoing changes to false. Then the reset() method have to keepGoing=true. It works but the while loop isn't working.

Class with reset() and checkWin():

```
private void reset() {
    b.x = 250;
    b.y = 100;
    b.keepRunning = true;
    a.keepGoing = true;
    System.out.println(a.keepGoing);
}

public void checkWin() {
    if (b.keepRunning) {
        if (b.getX() < -10) {
            a.score++;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(okno, "Player " + p.getScore()
                    + " - Computer " + a.getScore(), "Oh, well...",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            b.keepRunning = false;
            a.keepGoing = false;
            System.out.println(a.keepGoing);
            reset();
        } else if (b.getX() > 599) {
            p.score++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(okno, "Player " + p.getScore()
                    + " - Computer " + a.getScore(), "Good!",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            b.keepRunning = false;
            a.keepGoing = false;
            System.out.println(a.keepGoing);
            reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Second class with thread, keepGoing and the while loop:

```
Runnable intel = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (keepGoing) {
            while (getY() < board.ball.getY()) {
                System.out.println(keepGoing + " " + getY());
                try {
                    if (y == 220) {
                    } else {
                        y += 1;
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            while (getY() > board.ball.getY()) {
                System.out.println(keepGoing + " " + getY());
                try {
                    if (y == 0) {
                    } else {
                        y -= 1;
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the keyword `continue` to go to the next iteration of the loop. For example:

```
while(true)
{
   // ...

   if(!condition) continue; // this will go to the beginning of the while loop.

   // ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about if statement. I did it this way: `if(condition){//the rest of code}else{}` Thanks! :)

Comment: You should really have a second flag in the conditional or an example of a `break` statement to show how you would exit a loop with condition setup as `while(true)` but +1

Comment: Should probably sleep for a little while too even on a continue.

Answer (score 1):

If the `keepGoing` flag is accessed from different threads (which I think your example is showing, it's not clear), then you need to use synchronization to ensure that when you update the `keepGoing` flag in the reset() method, it is visible to the thread in your runnable. You might want to check out the `AtomicBoolean` class.

See Effective Java, Item #66

Comment: I think its more the fact that when the flag becomes false it quits the loop rather than keeps running in the background doing nothing, which means that when it becomes true again it isn't doing anything anymore.

Comment: @JonTaylor you are correct, that is the real reason it isn't working as designed. The concurrency problem is still valid, however, and is much more subtle as it will work **most** of the time, then mysteriously fail just when you don't want it to :)

Comment: I agree, it is deffinatley something to watch out for.