# Restart while loop if boolean == false

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I'm trying to get better at java by making a Sudoku puzzle, however I'm running in to some issues. As it currently stands, if I put any "illegal" input in the Sudoku, it just continues, but I'm trying to make the script ask for a value again if it is "illegal". As seen below in the code, it is when my public boolean "moves" is false I'm trying to start the while loop once again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    Sudoku s = new Sudoku("C:\\Users\\caspe\\Downloads\\Sudoku001.sdk");
    s.printBoard();
    s.errorCheck();
    s.getNum();

    while(getNum() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Next move, please (row , column , value )");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = scanner.nextInt();
        int column = scanner.nextInt() ;
        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        if (s.moves(row, column, value) == false); {
            //Try again
        }

        s.printBoard();
    }
}
```

I still can't figure out an solution after several different attempts, so help is very much appreciated!

This is my getNum method for further understanding:

```
public static int getNum() {
    int getNumb = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        for (int i=0; i < list.get(j).length(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).charAt(j) == '.') {
                getNumb++;
            }
        }
    }
    return getNumb;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the getNum method? What does it do?

Comment: you can use __continue__ to redo the loop again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restarting the while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437442/restarting-the-while-loop)

Comment: if i just use continue, my "printBoard" will be unreachable

Comment: What is ``list`` variable? What kind of object do you store in that list?

Comment: list is an arrayList of a sudoku which the program reads, sorry for missing information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have written your code it is going to print the Sudoku board whether s.move is true or false. The way you would fix that is by add in an else statement to your if statement.

For example:

```
if(s.moves(row, column, value) == false){
    //print error message
}else {
    s.printBoard();
}
```

Comment: I could have sworn i tried that solution.. Thanks however!